# Using (Bitmap image = new Bitmap(path)) Error.. Parameter not valid?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get an image but i get the error Parameter not valid with the following code.

```
 if (File.Exists(MapPath(tempFolderPathAlt + "ExtractedFiles\\" + boxPath + "\\" + ArrayNode[i].TagValue)))
    {
      using (Bitmap image = new Bitmap(MapPath(tempFolderPathAlt + "ExtractedFiles\\" + boxPath + "\\" + ArrayNode[i].TagValue)))
        {
          //other code
        }
    }
```

The inner exception is null.

[image]

The Path after this is mapped is:

> \C:\Users\Shaun\Documents\FormValue\ExtractedFiles\Box1e84b34a-522b-492e-919f-1334ee5845ff\ca4ac72a-9ca2-4a28-b4a4-a6031b734567.png

Comment: If your path actually starts with a back-slash that will be your problem.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko , so they need to be forward slash's?

Comment: I've seen this error when the file is empty as well

Comment: Hey thanks, i just checked my picture file and its empty.

Comment: @Petesh If you would post an answer i will gladly mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting an Invalid Parameter Exception for a new `Bitmap(String)`, where the file exists generally means that the file content is invalid and can't be parsed by any of the image type handlers.

One of the most common reasons for this is that the underlying file is of `0` size.

Answer (score 0):

I got this exception when **file** was **too large**.

to solve it, change '**FileSizeLimitInBytes**' in registry editor

1. .Click Start, type regedit in the Start Search box, and then press ENTER.
2. find HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters
3. select FileSizeLimitInBytes and change the value to bigger (more than 50000000)
4. restart your computer

If it still doesn't help, you change 'FsCtlRequestTimeoutInSec' too:

5. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\MRxDAV\Parameters
6. find FsCtlRequestTimeoutInSec and change the value to bigger (more than 1800 )

don't forget to restart your windows computer

for more details https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2668751/you-cannot-download-more-than-50-mb-or-upload-large-files-when-the-upl